# Resize numpy array with a lot of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm using Python 3.7.7. I'm trying to resize a Numpy image array with this function:

```
def resize_image_array(image_array, rows_standard, cols_standard):

    # image_array.shape = (3929, 2, 256, 256, 1)
    # rows_standard = 200
    # cols_standard = 200

    # Height or row number.
    image_rows_Dataset = np.shape(image_array)[2]
    # Width or column number.
    image_cols_Dataset = np.shape(image_array)[3]

    num_rows_1 = ((image_rows_Dataset // 2) - (rows_standard / 2)) # num_rows_1 = 28.0
    num_rows_2 = ((image_rows_Dataset // 2) + (rows_standard / 2)) # num_rows_2 = 228.0
    num_cols_1 = ((image_cols_Dataset // 2) - (cols_standard / 2)) # num_cols_1 = 28.0
    num_cols_2 = ((image_cols_Dataset // 2) + (cols_standard / 2)) # num_cols_2 = 228.0

    return image_array[..., num_rows_1:num_rows_2, num_cols_1:num_cols_2, :]
```

But in the last statement I get this error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I have also tried:

```
return image_array[:, :, num_rows_1:num_rows_2, num_cols_1:num_cols_2, :]
```

But with the same error as shown above.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: cast your indices to ints with `int()`. Even though they are "integers", they are still type `float`

Comment: Or rather, use integer division in the first place and you won't need to cast anything...

Comment: Why the mix of  `/` and `//`? `28.0` is not an `int`

Comment: Exactly. The OP knows how to do integer division, but hasn't used it consistently.

Comment: The OP doesn't know many things.

Comment: @VansFannel Okay, just change the single `/` to `//` and see how you get on.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and desired output? Just a shape is fine

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have added the input parameters values and shape as comments at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as mentioned in the comments, is that using true divide (`/`) on vanilla python scalars returns a `float`, even if both operands are integers. The operator does not check for integer divisibility before performing the division. `float`s do not have an `__index__` method, which converts int-like quantities to an actual `int`.

The simple solution is to replace `/` with `//`. However, the computation of `num_rows_2` and `num_cols_2` seems superfluous. If you know the values of `rows_standard` and `cols_standard` that you want, just add them to `num_rows_1` and `num_cols_1`, respectively. This will result in a much more robust expression:

```
row_start = (image_array.shape[2] - rows_standard) // 2
row_end = row_start + rows_standard
col_start = (image_array.shape[3] - cols_standard) // 2
col_end = col_start + cols_standard
image_array[..., row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end, :]
```